# Semaphore race condition?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, semaphore

I have created a "Manager" class that contains a limited set of resources.  The resources are stored in the "Manager" as a Queue.  I initialize the Queue and a Semaphore to the same size, using the semaphore to block a thread if there are no resources available.  I have multiple threads calling into this class to request a resource.  Here is the psuedo code:

```
public IResource RequestResource()
{
     IResource resource = null;
     _semaphore.WaitOne();

     lock (_syncLock)
     {
         resource = _resources.Dequeue();
     }
     return resource;
}
public void ReleaseResource(IResource resource)
{
    lock (_syncLock)
    {
        _resources.Enqueue(resource);
    }
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

While running this application, it seems to run fine for a while.  Then, it seems like my Queue is giving out the same object.  Does this seem like its possible?  I'm pulling my hair out over here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Feel free to ask for more information if you need it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls reformat and give us the code that is calling this ?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, i pasted in tabs and thought it looked right in the original preview, fixed now.

Comment: Does the queue size change when that happens? Is the object same even on different threads? What are the calling patterns? Did Enqueue and Dequeue throw any exceptions (you have bugs there, you know)? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: the queue and semaphore are synchronized.  when i call waitone, i remove and item from the queue, and vice versa.  im not sure what you mean by the same object even on different thread and the calling patterns.  enqueue and dequeue do not throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semaphore is really incidental here; that just limits the number of consumers that can acquire resources at the same time.  The synchronization is actually coming from the `lock` statement (critical section).

As far as I can tell, that code is thread-safe.  When you say it's "giving out the same object" - maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it *should* be giving out the same object, because when callers invoke the `Release` method, they put back the same resource they got originally, so the same object will be in the queue at several points during execution.

If what you mean is that the `RequestResource` method is returning resources that have already been acquired but not released, there are only three possible reasons that I can think of:

1. The queue contained duplicate resources from the beginning;
2. A consumer called the `Release` method twice.  In your `Release` method, you don't actually check to see whether or not the resource is already back in the queue; you might want to alter this code to check for this and throw an exception, which would help you catch where `Release` calls are being duplicated (if this is in fact the case).
3. Some other code is accessing the `_resources` queue without a `lock`.

My suspicion would be #2, if this is indeed what you mean by duplicates.

Comment: im trying number 2 now, let you know the results.  number one is not happening.  _resources is private and cannot be accessed outside the two methods calls, so i don't think that's an issue either.

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the issue.  I am going to attempt to make my processing more atomic, so I can try to narrow this error down.  If this fixes my problem, I still vote you up :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Aaronaught's answer:

It also looks entirely possible for two threads to acquire the semaphore, then one to enter  the critical section in `RequestResource()`, and the the other block, followed by the first thread completing all its work and returning the object to the queue with `ReleaseResource()` before the second thread waking up and having a chance to dequeue. That would give an impression of two threads obtaining the same object.

Comment: in principal, you are right.  the IResource takes around 10 seconds to do some work though, so it's not really an issue.  the "Resource" is being reused once its work is completed by another thread.  i can tell that a "Resource" is being used at the same time by different threads because the process is very synchronous, and in the middle of processing, it starts over and destroys my application.